# Writing from hashmap to a txt file

Tags: java, hashmap, bufferedreader, filewriter

I have a hashMap of Integer,String  (K,V) and want to write only the string values to a file (not the key Integer) and I want to write only some 1st n entries (no specific order) to the file and not the entire map.
I have tried looking around a lot but could not find a way to write 1st n entries to file.(There are examples where I can convert the value to array of Strings and then do it] but then it does not provide the correct format in which I want to write the file)

Comment: `then it does not provide the correct format in which I want to write the file` what is this format you speak of?

Comment: I want the strings to be printed as they are...1 on each line...and not in the form of a list [] i.e seperated by comma

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like homework.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // first, let's build your hashmap and populate it
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "Value1");
    map.put(2, "Value2");
    map.put(3, "Value3");
    map.put(4, "Value4");
    map.put(5, "Value5");

    // then, define how many records we want to print to the file
    int recordsToPrint = 3;

    FileWriter fstream;
    BufferedWriter out;

    // create your filewriter and bufferedreader
    fstream = new FileWriter("values.txt");
    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    // initialize the record count
    int count = 0;

    // create your iterator for your map
    Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

    // then use the iterator to loop through the map, stopping when we reach the
    // last record in the map or when we have printed enough records
    while (it.hasNext() && count < recordsToPrint) {

        // the key/value pair is stored here in pairs
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> pairs = it.next();
        System.out.println("Value is " + pairs.getValue());

        // since you only want the value, we only care about pairs.getValue(), which is written to out
        out.write(pairs.getValue() + "\n");

        // increment the record count once we have printed to the file
        count++;
    }
    // lastly, close the file and end
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps someone else will find it useful in researching a real problem.  It was easier to write the code than it was to banter back and forth with the asker trying to determine *why* the code was needed.  My apologies to the SO purists.  :)

Comment: it'd better you explain your code, w/o explanation this code is worthless. as you said it'd be useful for others if they understand. w/o explanation they could simply copy/paste . :)

Comment: Thanks dude...this is not HW question....I am new to java and got a little confused with the iterators and counters...the above explains what I need

Comment: nonetheless, I added some comments to explain what's happening in the loop.  It's more helpful than an uncommented block of code.

Comment: Can the same be done using PrintWriter? because I want to copy certain number of values from multiple hashmaps into the same file...

Comment: I'm sure it could, it would just be a matter of using PrintWriter instead.  Have a go at it, if you have any troubles let me know.

Comment: Well, its not my homework, yet it was very clear and helpful for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Just the flow ...

Get the iterator for values.
Iterate through them incrementing the counter.
Come out when the counter reaches n entries.

Other approach is to use

```
for(int i=0, max=hashmap.size(); i<max, i<n; i++) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the iterator with counter? I think that is what I need..

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Try this

1. Get the collection of values from the map.  Read the Map object reference and find the method named `values`.  Use this method
2. Iterate over the collection of values that you retrieved in step 1.  Write some (of your choosing) to a file.  Format as desired while writing.